# Fluent Interface vs Builder Pattern: Advantages and Disadvantages

Tags: java

When would one use fluent interface over a builder pattern and vice versa in Java?

I've been searching online for the differences between the two, but I still do not understand what situation would be appropriate to use one over the other. What advantages and disadvantages do each have over the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Builders basically always use a fluent interface. It isn't a case where you'd choose one or the other. The builder pattern is a type of object that typically uses a fluent interface. A fluent interface doesn't do anything by itself. It's just a popular way to write certain kinds of objects.

A fluent interface is when you have an object that returns itself, or something like itself. (I say *like* itself because it doesn't technically have to be itself, for example in the case of a step builder.) When you have `someObject.doA().doB().doC()` that's a fluent interface. Java `Stream` is also an example of using a fluent interface. (Although, technically the `Stream` object that you interact with is really a kind of builder. The stream only executes when you call a terminal operation like `forEach`. Everything before that was basically a builder and the terminal operation is analogous to a `build()` method.)

There are also lots of examples on Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface